# Flask - Calling a function within a function

Tags: python, flask

I'm sorry in advance for the rookie question. I'm learning Flask and I have a Python file that I'm now using in a Flask app. When I run the `app.py` file in Python (`python app.py`), everything works. However, when I run it in Flask, I get the error: `AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'tagger'`.

The `resTag` function is trying to return a response from the `Tagger` -> `tag` function. The result is the error message, mentioned above.

Any advice?

app.py

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def resTag():
    text = request.values['text']
    tokenized = request.values.get('tokenized') in ('1', 'True', 'true')
    return app.tagger.tag(text, tokenized)


class Tagger(object):
    def __init__(self, model, tokenizer, labels, config):
        self.model = model
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.labels = labels
        self.config = config
        self.session = None
        self.graph = None

    def tag(self, text, tokenized=False):
        # Stuff to do
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return statement should be `return Tagger.tag(text, tokenized)`

Comment: You're an angel. It works! Thank you! I've learned from this. I'll mark it soon! Thank you!